# How "blockies" are working?

Tags: metamask, wallets

Hm, I really like how are "blockies" looking in ethereum(a square colorful picture next to the user's address). I would like to know how and from what they are generated. Help me please)

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: [https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/ethereum-blockies-base64](https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/ethereum-blockies-base64#readme)

They are generated from an address that you pass to `makeBlockie` function. I'd suggest you take a closer look at the source code if you are curious how exactly the address is transformed into a blockie.

Comment: Thank u very much! But I still don’t understand logic of this code( In the title I see base64, but this is not mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum blockies...are generated using three method
First a seed is created,by which the colors of the blockies are made from,the spot color like the eyes and ear, the background color and the main image color, then an array of image data is created to map the color

0 -> background

1 -> main image

2 -> spot color

This data is then used to draw on a canvas

That is a brief summary on how they work

https://github.com/Imdavyking/blockies_ethereum